# Drop a table command in sqllite in android shows error-java.lang illegal argument exception : empty bind args

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hi i used this coding to drop my table

calling function

```
DatabaseHandler4 dbdelete1 = new   DatabaseHandler4(FiveActivity.this);

try {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Before delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dbdelete1.deleteall();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After Delet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Delete method this is the method to drop the table

```
public void deleteall()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_CONTACTS +"'" ;
    db.execSQL(selectQuery, null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Just remove the single quotes for table name

Comment: i tried it also shows the same error

Comment: Try removing second argument (null) to execSQL(); Eg. db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;)

Comment: If you do not have any bind arguments, use single argument version of execSQL(). Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the single quotes. Make your statement like so:

```
String selectQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
db.execSQL(selectQuery);
```

Maybe the variation of `execSQL` requiring two parameters is the problem? I don't think it works if you pass `null`, so try using the single-parameter version instead.

Answer (score 0):

problem is query string.
`"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + '"+TABLE_CONTACTS +"'`;

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME; use this syntax remove the Single Quotes from Syntax of DROP TABLE this might be the issue.